# Regular expression to match numbers followed by underscore and numbers?

Tags: java, javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to do validation in javascript. My requirement is to validate numbers followed by underscore and again it should have numbers.

```
For example: 123456789_123456789
```

Length is not a constraint. It can have `n` numbers, underscore and `n` numbers.
Currently i tried with this `[0-9]_[0-9]`. Is there any better way of doing it ?
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks,
Sreekanth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost got it. The correct regex would be :

```
^[0-9]{1,}_[0-9]{1,}$
```

or

```
^[0-9]+_[0-9]+$
```

The regex means: "*one or more digits* (`[0-9]{1,}`), *followed by an underscore* (`_`) *and then again one or more digits* (`[0-9]{1,}`).

This matches:

```
12312_123123
1_1
```

but doesn't match:

```
123123_
_123123
_
123123_1231ddd
123dd_123
dd123_123
```

Comment: Hi, It works fine with the above examples. It should also not allow 12121_12313dd. If i include alphabets before underscore it works as expected but if i include at the end it doesn't. can you please help

Comment: `{1,}` is more commonly written as `+`. Also, `{1}` doesn't make sense - omit it.

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers are optional: `/^\d*_\d*$/`, else: `/^\d+_\d+$/`.

Examples:

```
/^\d+_\d+$/.test("123_");    // false
/^\d+_\d+$/.test("123_123"); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

What You tried is `[0-9]_[0-9]`

*i.e,*

[image]

Possible Answer is `[0-9]+_[0-9]+`

*i.e,*

[image]